# How to define one specifc exception handler in Mediatr for all requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac, mediatr

I use Mediatr for an ASP.NET core project to handle all requests. I have several Request/Response/Handlers implemented. Each of them can throw a specific exception, let's call this "MyException" class.
I defined an exception handler as

```cs
    public class MyExceptionHandler : RequestExceptionHandler<MyRequest<MyResponse>, MyResponse, MyException>
    {
        protected override void Handle(MyRequest<MyResponse> request, MyException exception, RequestExceptionHandlerState<MyResponse> state)
        {
            MyResponse response = new MyResponse();
            //Set some specific properties here in the response to indicate an error occurred
            state.SetHandled(response);
        }
    }
```

I add this exception handler to the (Autofac) dependency container and this works if I throw a MyException in the MyHandler for MyRequest and MyResponse. However, I have dozens of requests, responses and corresponding handlers. So how can I register this exception handler for all of them for this specific exception (note: all responses are derived from a same base class). It tried something like the below, but, that does not get called. It only works if I give the actual types, but that would mean that I have to create an exception handler for each of the types, which is far from practical. Any ideas on how to solve this?

```cs
    public class MyExceptionHandler : RequestExceptionHandler<IRequest<BaseResponse>, BaseResponse, MyException>
    {
        protected override void Handle(IRequest<BaseResponse> request, MyException exception, RequestExceptionHandlerState<BaseResponse> state)
        {
            BaseResponse response = new BaseResponse();
            //Set some specific properties here in the response to indicate an error occurred
            state.SetHandled(response);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it a requirement that the exception handling has to take place in the mediatR pipeline? Perhaps an exception handling middleware would work.

Comment: You mean the ASP.NET core middleware? It seems to me that if I do not catch the exception in the pipeline (but with a try catch around the mediatr.Send method for example) I lose the actual type of exception that was thrown and it ends up as a generic Exception

Comment: Actually no, you will be able to get the exact exception that was thrown. It's common that a middleware is used to globally handle unhandled exceptions in the application. If you have an exception that is commonly thrown around the application and it's impractical to handle it in multiple places then this is a good approach. I can add an answer with the middleware approach if you're interested.

Comment: I've tried something like try { mediatr.send(...) } catch (MyEx) { ...} catch (Ex) {...}. The MyException never gets triggered if I throw the exception in the handler, it always goes to the regular Exception handler. In the debugger I also see the type of exception is the most generic one. If I cannot catch the specific exception here, how would ASP.NET Core middleware catch it then? Please post the middleware solution anyway, always interested to learn!

Answer (score 6):

You can create a generic one like this:

```
public class ExceptionLoggingHandler<TRequest, TResponse, TException> : IRequestExceptionHandler<TRequest, TResponse, TException>
         where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
         where TException : Exception
    {
        private readonly ILogger<ExceptionLoggingHandler<TRequest, TResponse, TException>> _logger;

        public ExceptionLoggingHandler(ILogger<ExceptionLoggingHandler<TRequest, TResponse, TException>> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public Task Handle(TRequest request, TException exception, RequestExceptionHandlerState<TResponse> state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogError(exception, "Something went wrong while handling request of type {@requestType}", typeof(TRequest));

            // TODO: when we want to show the user somethig went wrong, we need to expand this with something like
            // a ResponseBase where we wrap the actual response and return an indication whether the call was successful or not.
            state.SetHandled(default!);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

And then register it like this on a IerviceC:

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IRequestExceptionHandler<,,>), typeof(ExceptionLoggingHandler<,,>));
```

Because the `RequestExceptionProcessorBehavior` class will look for this type with 3 generics, instead of the `IRequestExceptionHandler<,>` one.

Comment: Thanks @rdvanbuuren, this seems like the most modern and correct approach. Can you elaborate on your example showing how to implement ResponseBase? I'm having trouble constraining generic parameters of `ExceptionLoggingHandler` so that I could correctly invoke `state.SetHandled`.

Comment: What would an ILogger implementation for this look like? Just a simple one that allowed Log method to invoke a lambda. For unit test.
I tried a new class implementing ILogger<ExceptionLoggingHandler<TRequest, TResponse, TException>>, but VStudio complains.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, the handlers are meant to be used for specific typed requests, responses and exceptions. `MediatR` in this case is not able to execute a generic variant, because that's [not how they are being resolved](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/master/src/MediatR/Pipeline/RequestExceptionProcessorBehavior.cs#L67), when an exception occurs.

So basically, what you have done is pretty close to what you are trying to achieve. You can create a generic abstract handler and have as many derived typed implementations as you need, but you will always have to create that boilerplate. Here a sample for a handler that catches an `InvalidOperationException`.

```cs
public class BaseResponse
{
    public bool Error { get; set; }

    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; } = null!;
}

public class SomeResponse : BaseResponse {}

public class BaseRequest<TResponse> : IRequest<TResponse> where TResponse : BaseResponse {}

public class SomeRequest : BaseRequest<SomeResponse> {}

public class SomeRequestHandler : IRequestHandler<SomeRequest, SomeResponse>
{
    public Task<SomeResponse> Handle(SomeRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}

public abstract class
    AbstractInvalidOperationExceptionHandler<TRequest, TResponse> : RequestExceptionHandler<TRequest, TResponse, InvalidOperationException>
    where TRequest : BaseRequest<TResponse>
    where TResponse : BaseResponse, new()
{
    protected override void Handle(TRequest request, InvalidOperationException exception, RequestExceptionHandlerState<TResponse> state)
    {
        var response = new TResponse
        {
            Error = true, 
            ErrorMessage = exception.Message
        };

        state.SetHandled(response);
    }
}

public class SomeInvalidOperationExceptionHandler : AbstractInvalidOperationExceptionHandler<SomeRequest, SomeResponse>
{
    
}
```

This should work as desired, requiring you to add one derived type for each combination of `TRequest` + `TResponse`. Each of those derived types also have to be manually registered, if you don't use the [Autofac-PlugIn for MediatR](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MediatR.Extensions.Autofac.DependencyInjection), which uses assembly-scanning to register all implementations of `RequestExceptionHandler<,,,>`.

There is a second option as well, which is similar to the suggested middleware but rather than writing a middleware, you would create one implementation for each exception of the interface `IExceptionFilter` (or `IAsyncExceptionFilter` if `async` is required here).

Given again handling the exception of type `InvalidOperationFilter` it would look something like that:

```cs
public class InvalidOperationExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception is not InvalidOperationException invalidOperationException)
        {
            return;
        }

        context.ExceptionHandled = true; // this follows the same principle as MediatR, you need to set it as handled, for the pipeline to stop executing!
        // this will set the response to 409
        context.Result = new ConflictObjectResult(new
        {
            Message = invalidOperationException.Message
        });
    }
}
```

Now this works pretty fine and that filter only needs to be registered once but it might not be the desired way of handling errors and returning them to the client. It also (tightly) couples your exception-handling logic to the framework.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach when you have the same type of exception being thrown in your MediatR handlers is to forgo the MediatR exception handlers and handle it globally via middleware. By doing that you ensure that you don't have the same piece of error-handling code scattered in multiple places.

Of course, you should consider will you always (to your best knowledge right now) handle the exception the exact same way, because if not that means that the middleware solution will most likely make your code less maintainable and clean if you start checking for custom conditions on the same exception.

So, here is an example middleware:

```
public class ValidationExceptionHandlerMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public ValidationExceptionHandlerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next) => this.next = next;

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await this.next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
        }
    }

    private static Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
    {
        switch (exception)
        {
            string result = "";
            case MyException validationException:
                //custom handling of my exception
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                result = //your serialized json object with error data
                break;
            default:
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                result = //your serialized json object with error data
                break;
        }

        return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
    }
}
```

What you then need to do is register this middleware in the pipeline where you see fit. You have to register it before the middlewares you want to be handled.

You can do it in the `Configure()` method in your `Startup.cs`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    builder.UseMiddleware<ValidationExceptionHandlerMiddleware>();
    ...
}
```

So now, all thrown and **unhandled** exceptions in the application will be handled by the middleware.

Take note that this is a lower-level solution that writes directly to the response, so if you need to execute business logic when handling the exception this might not be suitable.