# Mediatr - when throwing an exception from command handler app crashes and the exception remains unhandled

Tags: c#, .net-core, mediatr

```
public class Manager(IMediator mediatr)
{
    try
    {
        mediatr.Send(new DummyCommand());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         // Never gets called!
    }
}

public class DummyCommand : IRequest<DummyResponse>
{
}

public class DummyCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<DummyCommand, DummyResponse>
{
    public async Task<DummyResponse> Handle(DummyCommand
               command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new Exception("Dummy Error");
    }
}
```

Why doesn't the exception get propagated to the calling code?
I get unhandled exception in `ExceptionDispatchInfo` class of the `System.Runtime.ExceptionServices` namespace that the exception is unhandled

Decompiled IL:

```
    // When a framework needs to "Rethrow" an exception on a thread different (but not necessarily so) from
    // where it was thrown, it should invoke this method against the ExceptionDispatchInfo
    // created for the exception in question.
    //
    // This method will restore the original stack trace and bucketing details before throwing
    // the exception so that it is easy, from debugging standpoint, to understand what really went wrong on
    // the original thread.
    [DoesNotReturn]
    [StackTraceHidden]
    public void Throw()
    {
        // Restore the exception dispatch details before throwing the exception.
        _exception.RestoreDispatchState(_dispatchState);
        throw _exception;
    }
```

Is it still possible to catch the exception (I assume command handler handle is executed on a different thread), or should the error be captured in the response somehow?

Comment: The answer is likely in [this question and it's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65297156) Mediatr handles exceptions via a `RequestExceptionHandler`.

Comment: medatr.Send is an async function, I am guessing the catch does not work because you are not awaiting the Send call, and the handler execution hapens after the try block already finished executing.