# Log all exceptions in MediatR

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, mediatr

I'm trying to log any exception thrown by a MediatR handler using `IRequestExceptionAction`. I am not trying to [handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65297156/how-to-define-one-specifc-exception-handler-in-mediatr-for-all-requests) these exceptions. They may have already been handled.

I'm using Microsoft dependency injection have the `RequestExceptionActionProcessorStrategy` set to `ApplyForAllExceptions`.

If I implement a IRequestExceptionAction, where I give `T` the concrete type of a specific request, logging is successful:

```cs
public class RequestExceptionLogger : IRequestExceptionAction<ClientIndexPageQuery>
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public RequestExceptionLogger(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger(GetType());
    }

    public Task Execute(ClientIndexPageQuery request, Exception exception, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogError(exception,
            $"Exception occurred while attempting to handle request '{request.GetType().Name}': {exception.Message}");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

However, if I try to create a single handler to log exceptions from all handlers, it does not. Here are the two implementations I've tried:

#1: Generic handler

```cs
public class RequestExceptionLogger<T> : IRequestExceptionAction<T> where T : notnull
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public RequestExceptionLogger(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger(GetType());
    }

    public Task Execute(T request, Exception exception, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogError(exception,
            $"Exception occurred while attempting to handle request '{request.GetType().Name}': {exception.Message}");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

#2: Use `IRequest` as TRequest

```cs
public class RequestExceptionLogger : IRequestExceptionAction<IRequest>
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public RequestExceptionLogger(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger(GetType());
    }

    public Task Execute(IRequest request, Exception exception, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogError(exception,
            $"Exception occurred while attempting to handle request '{request.GetType().Name}': {exception.Message}");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

How do I add a single pipeline behavior that will fire for exceptions for all MediatR handlers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define one specifc exception handler in Mediatr for all requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65297156/how-to-define-one-specifc-exception-handler-in-mediatr-for-all-requests)

Comment: @MDZand is similar, but not the same. That is an exception handler, which is different than an exception action filter. I will update question to clarify. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Same issue here. Did you ever solve this?